# Why do I get this unreachable error when I try to get the value from JSpinner?

Tags: java, user-interface, applet, jspinner, unreachable-statement

Can Someone help me? I keep getting this error but don't know what to do. Thanks!!!

```
FrogsJSpinner.addChangeListener( new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        Number.totalFrogPrice = Double.parseDouble(ce.getSource().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you expect lines after an exception is thrown to execute?

Comment: oh! The error is unreachable statement.

Comment: oh! I got it, but why do they want to throw that exception?

Comment: Looks like the reason is because the operation isn't supported, hence the name `UnsupportedOperationException`. Probably something work in progress or under development and not implemented yet.

Comment: I delete         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.   and is good to go

Comment: Because it won't throw and exception, thus it won't stop execution allowing the statement to be reachable :)

Comment: if there are three different JSpinner, how can I use switch statement to catch the right one if JSpinner doesn't even have a ID? Because I don't wanna create three anonymous class.

Comment: I suspect that you're supposed to replace that with whatever implementation you need to provide.